# ImageMagick -fuzz OR gravity center cropping with things that fit in a scalable aspect ratio box

Tags: graphics, imagemagick

First, the goal of this task is to get images to be visually as large as possible by removing excess around the the edges.

I have tried **fuzz** and -gravity center and they both do a good job although I think I prefer gravity.

There is a small issue though, and that is the cropping leads to images that are not retaining aspect ratio and therefore are visually non conformant to the place where they are to be displayed.

**I will demonstrate using images:**

I **start** with this input image **(800x800)**, pay attention to **edges**:

[image: 800x800]

When I apply the command `magick "${file}" -gravity center -trim "${out}"`

I get the following output **(696x656)**, where you can see whitespace at the top and bottom edge. This is kind of ok here, however, the image sits next to another image and the difference in height is quite annoying to see. This might be ok, here but there are worse examples.

[image]

**Instead**, aspect ratio should be kept, and in this case, the previous image should **retain the parts** that are **white** around the edges.

A quite complex attempt to solve this was to recalculate the height to **696** which does work to get extra pixels **but they** are however white pixels and not the underlying images pixels:

`magick "${file}" -gravity center -trim -extent "696x696" "${out}"`

[image]

This white edges are now in fact part of the image where the first ones are not so aspect ratio is kept but in a rather clunky way.

So the only problem is how to tell gravity center to retain those parts.

Ideally though, any gravity operation should be performed using an aspect ratio in mind and the gravity operation should find the best scaled aspect ratioed square to use for cropping.

On another note, what is the info return values widthxheight+something+something? What are the somethings?

Comment: You need to add -fuzz XX%. For JPG it needs to be about 15% due to compression artifacts. If other scanning spots, it may have to be larger or other processing done to remove the small extraneous spots.

Comment: @fmw42 you sure you understood the question? The problem is retaining scale.

Comment: No, I did not understand that until just now and was going to delete my post. I do not see how -trim can add white padding to the top and bottom. ..... One thought would be to trim and resize to the original aspect ratio. But that may crop some of your image. Or trim and crop or trim and extent to the desired aspect ratio. You may want to look into -resize W:H or -crop W:H or -extent W:H, such as 3:2. Where W:H is the width to height aspect ratio

Comment: @fmw42 dude! you made me try extent with : rather than x ... and it seems to obey the ratio desired! it even crops down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I've got it:

`magick "${file}" -gravity center -trim -extent "800x800" "${out}"`

Will give me

[image]

and

`magick "${file}" -gravity center -trim -extent "800:800" "${out}"`

Will give me:

[image]

So the x is to be switched for a :

Note that:

`magick "${file}" -gravity center -trim -extent "696x696" "${out}"`

will give

[image]

and so rather than put back the height ImageMagick goes a step further and tries to crop more from the width which is actually the desirable, albeit a bit of the **snails tail** seems to be cut in picture two.

There should be an option I guess for how aggressive it is to walk between expanding height vs eating width.

But I am quite satisfied. Thanks @fm42!

**EDIT**

This is not always ideal, that it goes for the width rather than fill the whitespace:

This:

[image]

now leads to:

[image]

Comment: You can specify -gravity to crop in center or west or east or however you want.

Comment: Would a mode to pad by aspect ratio rather than crop be useful for you?

Comment: @fmw42 problem is I don't know how the image will look like. I am using center however.

Comment: @fmw42 What is the pad mode? How do I change the command?

Comment: The extent pad does not exist yet. I was asking if that would be useful. It would specify an aspect ratio for -extent and in place of cropping to the aspect ratio, it would pad to the aspect ratio.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what is happening now though with extent. I am getting hte white borders. I solved it however using some complex logic to manually crop things out.

Comment: -extent will pad normally, but not to a specified aspect ratio. That is what I am asking if it would useful.

Comment: i think using x:y did that already. We are passed that now. Gravity in general was not great. Using trim is enough for me albeit not great. I had to manually compensate for growing but at least it is working now:

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. It is very hard to read.